# Play! - Many to many relationship on same model class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have a simple model class in my Play! application:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    public String login;
    public String password;
    public String fullName;
    public Date lastLogin;


    public List<User> following;

    public List<User> followedBy;

}
```

How to properly annotate and/or modify this class to be able to fetch users that current user is following and fetch users that are following current user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    public String login;
    public String password;
    public String fullName;
    public Date lastLogin;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followedBy") public List<User> following;
    @ManyToMany public List<User> followedBy;
}
```